# Can we use Admob ad in multiple activities

Tags: android, admob

I am using one Admob ad in my app,it is perfectly displaying the ad.
Now can I use that same ad in all remaining activities in my app,I mean can I use same publisher id and ad id in multiple activities.

My doubt is, it takes time to show ad or it is an illegal activity as per admob policies.

This is the block of code am using

```
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), add_key_vehicle_page);
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

This is ad layout code in xml

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
android:theme="@style/Base.CardView"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
```

Please tell me..

Comment: what if you firstly give it a try and then consider it posting as a question if it gives any error

Comment: I have tried this but no ad showing in my app,that's am posting this question.my doubt is, it takes time to show ad or it is an illegal activity as per admob policies.

Comment: ok then show some code what you are using

Comment: now am sharing block of my code

Comment: try my below given answer..

Comment: Is my answer works ??

Comment: Actually ad take some time to display in my app,now all my ads are displaying with my previous code,Thanks @RahulKhurana

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150906/discussion-between-dhanu-k-and-rahul-khurana).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here

```
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), add_key_vehicle_page);
```

instead use

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, add_key_vehicle_page);
```

inside each activity

Comment: Why is the application context a problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to the AdMob help documents, you need a differend block ID for each activity.